# Likelihood of getting a question answered

Tags: discussion, statistics

I was wondering if there were any statistics which could indicate around what time of the day are questions getting answered most often.

I.e., the likelihood of getting an answer to a question asked as a function of time during the day. Are there any graphs available or other kind of information?

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3865/depending-on-the-tag-is-there-a-possibility-to-know-on-which-days-and-hours-are

Comment: Well I'm lookin' at some data over here and it seems that, first of all, it varies highly from day to day, and second of all that there isn't much of a pattern even within the days.  But my data comes from a general "answers per hour" graph, it would be better to look through SQL to make some cuts and normalize.